# Remove one of activitys icon from launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers, android-launcher

I write a test app with several icon in launcher,such as icon A,icon B and icon C.

What I do like follow:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();     
ComponentName mComponentName = new ComponentName("com.i.test","com.i.test.Aofactivitys");
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(mComponentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But it will remove all my app icons from launcher.

What should I do can remove only one icon from launcher? At the same time,the icon b & icon c still display in launcher.

Comment: you could remove the launcher part from the manifest in the activity you don't want to show

Comment: I mean I can remove or display icon in code.